# Diffeomorphism Invariance of Terms in Lagrangian which use Gauge Fields

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, differential-geometry, gauge-theory, gauge-invariance, diffeomorphism-invariance

A term in a Lagrangian is gauge invariant if one makes sure to use quantities which transform in proper representations of the group of gauge transformations.  This means that one cannot write terms in the Lagrangian using a 'bare' gauge field, but one can use the associated field strength or act on a gauge field with a covariant derivative.

On the other hand, if one writes a term using a 'bare' gauge field (for example, a combination of the gauge field and the associated field strength tensor), although it will not be gauge invariant, will this term still be invariant under diffeomorphisms of the spacetime on which the field theory is defined?

Since diffeomorphism invariance is sometimes taken informally to be ''background independence of the field theory'', I guess that this term should be invariant under diffeomorphisms?  Or does diffeomorphism invariance fail because it is a specific example of a gauge symmetry?

Comment: The gauge field is not a tensor of $GL(d,R)$ so anything thing that depends explicitly on it will not be diffeomorphism invariant.

Comment: Are the usual Christoffel symbols a tensor of $GL (d, R)$?

Comment: no. they are connections.